# Executing functions with arguments from a list of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a list with elements of type `{ funcToExecute: (arg: U) => void; input: U }`. I wish to execute the functions inside using `forEach` and the appropriate input. My problem is that the arguments of `funcToExecute` can be of different types. Consider this example:

```
const functionA = (arg: number) => {
  console.log(arg + 2);
};

const functionB = (arg: string) => {
  console.log(parseInt(arg) + 2);
};

const foo = [
  { funcToExecute: functionA, input: 12 },
  { funcToExecute: functionB, input: `12` },
];

foo.forEach(e => e.funcToExecute(e.input)); // error: 'string | number' is not assignable to never
```

I can get around the type system by using something like this:

```
type functionWithInput<U> = {
  funcToExecute: (arg: U) => void;
  input: U;
};

foo.forEach((e: functionWithInput<any>) => e.funcToExecute(e.input)); // ok, but not type safe
```

Is there an elegant solution to my problem?

Comment: Looks like another one to throw on the [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) pile.  There isn't anything much better than a type assertion here for now, I'm afraid.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, [it's not pretty](https://tsplay.dev/kNrlDW).